# Sort alphanumeric SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server

How to sort the below following values from column `Operation_type`?

```
1.Administration
13.Legal And Contractual Matters
14.Financial
15.Personnel
16.Procurement Of Materials, Works And Services
21.Business Management
3.Information System
```

I tried the below approach but it fails to execute.

```
select distinct(Operation_type) 
from tableA  
order by cast(case when Operation_type like '%[0-9]' then right(Operation_type , 1) else null end as int)
```

Below is the expected output:

```
1.Administration
3.Information System 
13.Legal And Contractual Matters
14.Financial
15.Personnel
16.Procurement Of Materials, Works And Services
21.Business Management
```

PS: I need to get the distinct column values, not using select *

Comment: Store the number separately. Numerical values don't sort in the same order as alphanumerical values. `'2'` is **greater than** `'10'`; as you have found out.

Comment: I'm presuming that you want to sort them numerically?

Comment: @Martin yes. I have updated the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CHARINDEX` to find the position of the dot (`.`) in the column and use the numbers before this to `ORDER` your output:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA  
  ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(Operation_type, CHARINDEX('.', Operation_type) - 1) AS INT)
```

This is entirely dependent on their always being a dot (`.`) in the column though.

A working fiddle showing this is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/653b64/8/0).

If you can't guarantee that the dot is always present, this version uses a sub-query to deal with entries that do not contain it:

```
SELECT Operation_type
  FROM (
        SELECT *,
               CASE
                 WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Operation_type) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(Operation_type, CHARINDEX('.', Operation_type) - 1) AS INT)
                 ELSE 0
               END AS OrderCol
          FROM tableA  
       ) a
  ORDER BY OrderCol
```

In this case, the entries without a dot will appear first in the list.  You could move them to the end by changing `ELSE 0` to a larger value.

**Edit following comment about DISTINCT results**

The following modified query also handles duplicate rows using `DISTINCT` as you requested:

```
SELECT Operation_type
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT(Operation_type),
               CASE
                 WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Operation_type) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(Operation_type, CHARINDEX('.', Operation_type) - 1) AS INT)
                 ELSE 0
               END AS OrderCol
          FROM tableA  
       ) a
  ORDER BY OrderCol
```

Comment: I want to use distinct of that column.

Comment: @eshaa I've updated the answer to also include outputting distinct results only.

Answer (score 2):

I would change your `ORDER BY` to something like below:

```
select Operation_type
from (
    select distinct(Operation_type) Operation_type
    from #tableA
    ) tmp
order by CAST(LEFT(operation_type, charindex('.', operation_type) - 1) as int)
```

Full working script:

```
create table #tableA (operation_type nvarchar(max))

insert into #tableA (operation_type) values (
'1.Administration'), (
'13.Legal And Contractual Matters'), (
'14.Financial'), (
'15.Personnel'), (
'16.Procurement Of Materials, Works And Services'), (

select Operation_type
from (
    select distinct(Operation_type) Operation_type
    from #tableA
    ) tmp
order by CAST(LEFT(operation_type, charindex('.', operation_type) - 1) as int)
```

And the output of the above query:

[image]

Comment: with select * it works. but I need to get distinct column values.

Comment: @eshaa updated my answer to solve the distinct "problem"

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do it like this and move the number to a different column, to normalise the data:

```
WITH VTE AS
    (SELECT YourString
     FROM (VALUES ('1.Administration'),
                  ('13.Legal And Contractual Matters'),
                  ('14.Financial'),
                  ('15.Personnel'),
                  ('16.Procurement Of Materials, Works And Services'),
                  ('21.Business Management'),
                  ('3.Information System')) V (YourString) )
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int,L.Num) AS Num,
       STUFF(V.YourString, 1, LEN(L.Num) + 1, '') AS YourString
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (LEFT(V.YourString, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', V.YourString), 0) - 1))) L (Num)
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(int, L.Num);
```